# Can't run a Homebrew app from batch file in WSL bash (command not found)

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, homebrew, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a bash script that contains the following commands, including passing a file to [eyeD3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which I installed using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /mnt/c/Users/charl/Downloads;
eyeD3 test.mp3;
```

When I run it in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) from my Ubuntu bash prompt, I get the correct result:

```
thompcha@WINDOWS-79UTJUF:/mnt/c/Users/charl/Documents/Scripts$ ./eyed3.sh
/mnt/c/Users/charl/Downloads/test.mp3                                                     [ 7.15 MB ]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 04:26     MPEG1, Layer III        [ 224 kb/s @ 44100 Hz - Stereo ]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID3 v2.4:
title: Example Song
artist: Example Artist
album: Example Album
track: 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, if I run the bash script from a batch file like this,

```
@ECHO OFF
bash.exe -c ./eyed3.sh
PAUSE
```

the eyeD3 command cannot be run:

```
./eyed3.sh: line 3: eyeD3: command not found
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Default system commands like `ls` can be run in this way from a shell script called by a batch file, but `eyeD3` cannot. I'm guessing that the script cannot "see" the environment $PATH when it is run this way, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

I have unchecked "Use legacy console" in the cmd.exe properties.

How can I run a homebrew command in a shell script from a batch file?

Comment: What does happen on referencing the executable `eyeD3` with full qualified file name in the shell script, i.e. with full path in Windows Subsystem for Linux environment?

Comment: Re:Mofi's comment -- For instance, while in the shell (where you know it works), do a `which eyed3` and then hardcode the fully qualified path in the shell script.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds this command produced `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/eyeD3`, which works a charm! Is there a way to make it include this path when running commands that don't contain a path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - Several options:

- Option 1: Change it to `bash.exe -l -c ./eyed3.sh`.  I'm fairly sure that will work (see below for "why").
- Option 2:  As per the comments, identify the location of the eyeD3 executable with `which eyeD3` in the terminal where it works, then hardcode the fully-qualified path in the shell script.
- Option 3:  Set the Homebrew path in your `.bashrc` rather than your `.profile` (where Homebrew set it).

/aside: Wow, it's been more than 15 years since I used eyeD3.  Amazing that it is still around and kicking!

### What's happening

I don't run Homebrew, but looking at its [install script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh) (the last 10 lines or so) confirms my hunch that it adds its path to your `.profile` (or other applicable startup script) during its installation.

`.profile` (or `.bash_profile` or ...) is only sourced for login shells (usually the "top level" shell that spawns other non-login shells).  It's the place for things that should only be done "once" when logging in, rather than in each shell instance.  The PATH is set here because it is exported to subshells, so it doesn't need to be set each time.

So when you run `bash.exe -c ./eyeD3.sh`, that's actually a non-login shell, and it skips the login startup scripts, and thus skips the code that Homebrew added to modify the PATH.  Running `bash` with the `-l` argument will cause it to run as a login shell, thus sourcing that Homebrew code, and modifying the PATH for that shell.

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/8882/what-is-the-difference-between-a-login-and-an-interactive-bash-shell) for some more detail on the different types of startup scripts, if you are interested.